# Which TTS is google translate using? Is there a way to use this TTS in android app too?

Tags: android, google-translate, text-to-speech

I found for certain languages the sound files from google translate sound by far most real (compared to other TTS engines availlable for Android).

Is the google translate app using a TTS engine?

Is there a way to play these TTS from a android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to a TechCrunch article on using the unofficial Google TTS API [http://techcrunch.com/2009/12/14/the-unofficial-google-text-to-speech-api/].  You pass in the text in a RESTful API and it returns you an MP3.  So if you can make an HTTP request from your Android application and play the MP3 that is returned you could use the Google TTS engine. The downside is that it is "unofficial" so it could be changed or removed without warning.  There are probably other services available like this that are supported.  But you will need an Internet connection and have to deal with latency issues with this approach, which may or may not be an issue depending on the application.

Comment: Thanks. That's basically what I searched for. But according to the article it is English only. And there is no parameter passed to select the language. But the basic idea is good (just wondering myself why I didn't think in this direction.......)

Comment: Found the answer in the comments: http://www.ispeech.org seems to be sufficient for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Android uses TTS engine, but the engine is determined by the firmware provider.  The most-commonly seen one is Pico.

Here is the Android documentation on using TTS:
[android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html)

Comment: Thats clear so far. But my meaning was different. Which TTS is the google translate app using and is there a way to use it too (because for certain languages google translate just sounds more real than other available TTS engines - personal opinion)?

Answer (score 0):

Android's TTS does NOT require an internet connection. It generates the sounds as needed.

Here is some code that uses Android TTS. It handles some of the gotchas involved:

https://github.com/gmilette/Say-the-Magic-Word-